# Tips for speeding up my Python/Cython code

Tags: python, performance, cython, cellular-automata

I have written a Python program and Cythonize it. The speed-up gained by Cython (30%) wasn't satisfying. There is definitely room to optimise it by either changing the code structure or the way it is Cythonized.

The program is basically takes a digital elevation model (DEM) raster map and a excess water map with the same shape. For each pixel in the excess water map, it searches for the four neighbouring pixels and determines if the pixel is lower than surrounding neighbors, has same level or is higher than them. Based on this, it increases water level at the pixel or divides its excess water among neighbours that have lower elevation. The code continues until all the excess water is spread over the ground. Here's the Cython version of the code.

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cdef unravel(np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim = 1] idx,int shape0, int shape1):
    return idx//shape0, idx%shape1

cdef find_lower_neighbours(int i, int j, np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=2] water_level, double friction_head_loss):

    cdef double current_water_el, minlevels, deltav_total, deltav_min
    current_water_el = water_level[i,j]
    cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim = 1] levels = np.zeros(4, dtype = np.double)

    levels[:] = water_level[i - 1, j], water_level[i, j + 1], water_level[i + 1, j], water_level[i, j - 1]
    minlevels = levels.min()

    if current_water_el - minlevels < 0:
        return 0, minlevels, 0

    elif np.absolute(current_water_el - minlevels) < 0.0001:
        res = np.where(np.absolute(levels - current_water_el) < 0.0001)
        return 1, res[0], 0

    else:
        levels = current_water_el - levels
        low_values_flags = levels < 0
        levels[low_values_flags] = 0

        deltav_total = np.sum(levels)
        deltav_min = levels[levels > 0].min()
        return 2, levels / (deltav_total + deltav_min), deltav_min / (deltav_total + deltav_min)


cpdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=2] new_algorithm( np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=2] DEM, np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim=2] extra_volume_map, double nodata, double pixel_area, double friction_head_loss , int von_neuman):

    cdef int terminate = 0
    cdef int iteration = 1

    cdef double sum_extra_volume_map


    index_dic_von_neuman = [[-1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, -1]]
    cdef int DEMshape0 = DEM.shape[0]
    cdef int DEMshape1 = DEM.shape[1]

    cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim = 2] water_levels
    water_levels = np.copy(DEM)

    cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim = 2] temp_water_levels
    temp_water_levels = np.copy(water_levels)

    cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t, ndim = 2] temp_extra_volume_map
    temp_extra_volume_map = np.copy(extra_volume_map)


    cdef np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim = 2] wetcells
    wetcells = np.zeros((DEMshape0,DEMshape1), dtype= np.int)
    wetcells[extra_volume_map > 0] = 1

    cdef np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim = 2] temp_wetcells
    temp_wetcells = np.zeros((DEMshape0,DEMshape1), dtype= np.int )

    cdef double min_excess = friction_head_loss * pixel_area
    cdef np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim = 1] fdx
    cdef int i, j , k, condition, have_any_dry_cells_in_neghbors
    cdef double water_level_difference, n , volume_to_each_neghbour, weight, w0

    if von_neuman == 0:
        index_dic = index_dic_von_neuman


    while terminate != 1:
        fdx = np.flatnonzero(extra_volume_map > min_excess)
        extra_volume_locations = unravel(fdx, DEMshape1,DEMshape1)
        if not extra_volume_locations[0].size:
            terminate = 1
            return water_levels

        for item in zip(*extra_volume_locations):
            i = item[0]
            j = item[1]

            if DEM[i,j] == nodata:
                print "warningggggg", i, j
                temp_extra_volume_map[i,j] = 0.
            else:
                condition, wi, w0 = find_lower_neighbours(i, j, water_levels, friction_head_loss)

                if condition == 0:
                    water_level_difference = wi - water_levels[i,j]
                    temp_water_levels[i,j] = wi
                    temp_extra_volume_map[i,j] -= water_level_difference * pixel_area

                elif condition == 1:
                    n = len(wi)
                    volume_to_each_neghbour = (extra_volume_map[i, j] - friction_head_loss * pixel_area * .02)/ (n * 1. )
                    for itemm in wi:
                        temp_extra_volume_map[i + index_dic[itemm][0], j + index_dic[itemm][1]] += volume_to_each_neghbour
                        temp_wetcells[i + index_dic[itemm][0], j + index_dic[itemm][1]] += 1
                    temp_extra_volume_map[i,j] -= extra_volume_map[i,j]
                    temp_water_levels[i,j] += friction_head_loss * .02

                elif condition == 2:
                    temp_wetcells[i,j] += 1
                    have_any_dry_cells_in_neghbors = 0 # means "no"
                    for k, weight in enumerate(wi):
                        if weight > 0:
                            temp_extra_volume_map[i + index_dic[k][0], j + index_dic[k][1]] += weight * (extra_volume_map[i,j])
                            if wetcells[i + index_dic[k][0], j + index_dic[k][1]] == 0:
                                have_any_dry_cells_in_neghbors = 1
                            temp_wetcells[i + index_dic[k][0], j + index_dic[k][1]] += 1
                    if have_any_dry_cells_in_neghbors == 1:
                        temp_water_levels[i,j] += friction_head_loss
                        temp_extra_volume_map[i, j] -= (1. - w0) * (extra_volume_map[i, j])
                    else:
                        temp_extra_volume_map[i, j] -= (1. - w0) * (extra_volume_map[i, j])


        wetcells = np.copy(temp_wetcells)
        water_levels = np.copy(temp_water_levels)
        extra_volume_map = np.copy(temp_extra_volume_map)

        iteration += 1
        if iteration*1. %500. == 0.:
            sum_extra_volume_map = np.sum(extra_volume_map)
            print "iteration", iteration, "volume left =",  sum_extra_volume_map


    print "finished at iteration =", iteration - 1

    return water_levels
```

Here is the result of profiling:

```
6712150 function calls in 29.005 seconds

Ordered by: standard name

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
      1    0.000    0.000   29.005   29.005 <string>:1(<module>)
2017444    0.497    0.000    4.414    0.000 _methods.py:28(_amin)
289757    0.070    0.000    0.543    0.000 _methods.py:31(_sum)
289757    0.437    0.000    1.098    0.000 fromnumeric.py:1730(sum)
506055    0.203    0.000    0.705    0.000 function_base.py:1453(copy)
168685    0.140    0.000    0.300    0.000 numeric.py:859(flatnonzero)
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 test.py:22(print_dem_for_excel)
     1    0.000    0.000   29.005   29.005 test.py:27(test)
289757    0.119    0.000    0.119    0.000 {isinstance}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
    20    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {map}
    20    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
    20    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
168685    0.106    0.000    0.106    0.000 {method 'nonzero' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
168685    0.054    0.000    0.054    0.000 {method 'ravel' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
2307201    4.390    0.000    4.390    0.000 {method 'reduce' of 'numpy.ufunc' objects}
 506056    0.501    0.000    0.501    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.array}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {numpy.core.multiarray.zeros}
     1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {time.time}
     1   22.488   22.488   29.005   29.005 {version3Cython.new_algorithm}
```

Comment: Don't expect SO to do your work .....

Comment: I'm sorry if my question is interpreted in this way. I thought by putting the whole algorithm SO professionals can see areas that I don't even know is possible to improve.

Comment: `cython -a` is a good first place to look. Things like an untyped `index_dic_von_neuman = ...` are going to kill your performance.

Comment: @Veedrac Untyped items in my code are Python objects (list, dictionary, ...) should I try to avoid using them or there is a specific way to declare their type? I'm having problem interpreting the -a html file, I should learn how to use it. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

You need first to [profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) your program and measure precisely what takes time (what functions consume the most CPU time).

You could improve the algorithms in your program and lower the [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) of some of your functions.

You could also *manually* rewrite the heavy (resource demanding, e.g. CPU consuming) parts of your code, e.g. as [Python extensions](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html) in (hand written) C (perhaps also with some parts in C++ or any language easily callable from C and compatible with the memory models of Python and C). Don't expect any tool (e.g. Cython) to do that automatically and efficiently.

Your program is small enough. Consider spending a few weeks (or months) in rewriting some parts of it, or even redesigning and rewriting it entirely. I guess that statically typed compiled languages (like Ocaml, Go, D, C++) could provide some performance improvement. Perhaps you might consider *redesigning entirely* your code as a concurrent application (multi-[threaded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)), or [OpenCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL), [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface), ....)

Look at the existing Python prototype as just a way to begin understanding the problem you are tackling, but redesign and rewrite your code entirely (probably in a different language). Spend also some time reading existing literature on the subject and discussing with experts.

BTW, an execution time of less than a minute might be considered acceptable by your users. Then you don't need to rewrite code. Remember that your development time has some costs too! There is [*No Silver Bullet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet) ...

Comment: Run time for a real case takes around 3 hours. Besides I will run this algorithm for many cases at the same time, so I can take all the computational resources I have.

Comment: It is your decision to decide if spending a month of work (and perhaps even several, depends upon your current skills) is worthwhile. Remember [Hofstadter's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hofstadter%27s_law). Perhaps speak with your PhD advisor.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch great answer

Comment: With respect to profiling, Cython does support line by line profiling (which might give additional insight)

Comment: Thanks @DavidW, didn't know about it. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch your answer and comments have many interesting key words. Thanks! I should edit my question and perhaps make it more specifically about Cython.

Comment: Don't expect dramatic improvements from any automatic optimizer, even Cython or something more evolved.

Comment: Downvoting because I honestly don't think you're answering the question, and your comments on Cython are misleading: for straightforward numerical code there is very little reason that simple Cython shouldn't roughly match simple C for performance.